# Bold symbol in math-mode, but normal subscript?

Tags: math-mode, bold

I want my subscript on **F**  in the first equation to be like the subscript on **A** in the second equation.

I've tried to use `\emph{ }` to override the bolding, but this makes the spacing and sizing of the subscript smaller/closer together than that for **A**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
Y_i = \bf{F}_{ij} \bf{B} + e_{i}\\
Y_i = A_{ij} = 1,2,...,N \notag
\end{gather}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\bf` is incorrectly used here; use `\mathbf`, which takes a parameter to set it in **bold** font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  Y_i = \mathbf{F}_{ij} \mathbf{B} + e_{i}\\
  Y_i = A_{ij} = 1,2,\dotsc,N \notag
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

As a side note, [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\dotsc` for a math-related `\ldots` between commas. See section **4.3 Dots** (p 11 & 12) of the [`amsmath` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) for all kinds of math-related dot-commands.

Comment: Nice. Why do you use \dotsc over "..."?

Comment: @IssacM: I've added some reference to `\dotsc` in the [`amsmath` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf).